# How to create a custom R 'property' (e.g. dim())

Tags: r

So I basically want to create a 'property' in R which I haven't really found documentation or other SO Q/A explaining how this works.

So an example of what I'm looking for to make a function `property` with the behavior found in some base R functions (e.g. dim(), names(), attr(), etc...), where you can do `property(variable) = value` and then have `property(variable) == value` be true.

I was hoping that this would work:

```r
x = 1
property = function(x) attr(x, 'property')
`property<-` = function(x, value) attr(x, 'property') <<- value
property(x) = 2
property(x)
```

But it didn't and in hindsight I have no idea how I would do this since x is copied by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `` `attr<-` `` in your function.

```
x <- 1
property <- function(x) attr(x, 'property')
`property<-` <- function(x, value) `attr<-`(x, 'property', value) 
property(x) <- 2
property(x)
# [1] 2
```

Or, using your code, you need to do `return(x)` after assigning something to it.

```
`property<-` <- function(x, value) {attr(x, 'property') <- value;x}
property(v) <- 2
property(v)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Curious why attr(x, 'property') <- value doesn't work and this does?

Comment: @profPlum Actually it would work, but your function doesn't return anything. See edit.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess that's the general form of those functions then were the variable takes on the returned value. Thanks this was very informative.

Comment: @profPlum I saw that you use `<<-` and my guess was, that the assignment won't get the environment right, and we'd need to do something using `assign`. Anyway, we have two ways that work.